# JSHint Exponentiation operator (**) warning?

Tags: javascript, operators, jshint, exponentiation

***Problem :***

in VSCode editor I got this warning message that's JSHint dropped

```
Expected an identifier and instead saw '*'. (E030)
```

for syntaxes like :

```
const precise = (n, d = 2) => int(n * 10 ** d) / 10 ** d;
```

in my code I have write syntaxes used [Exponentiation operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Exponentiation_(**)) (**) and it's work correctly (perfectly) in working target environment.

***Question :***

my Question is there a way to turn off/suppress this type of warnings **globally** using JSHint options, because my project it's large and modular, and this warnings shown in many particular modules which disturb when following warnings.

*Note :* I've use [Exponentiation assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators#Exponentiation_assignment) also

Comment: Are you using `esversion: 7` when you run jshint? The exponentiation operator is not in ES2015.

Comment: @Pointy , my jshint version is 2.9.6(latest until now), when I try to change `esversion` option to `7` dropped and error for no options like this in VSCode user settings; and it's not work as they described in they Docs [link](https://jshint.com/docs/options/#esversion).

Comment: Well that's what I got from the jshint github issues. The point is that exponentiation is not part of ES2015 (ES6), so it's technically not valid ES2015 JavaScript.